# Unable to get property 'then' using promises

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, winjs, promise

I want to have the most clear code into my app. So I decided to separate the xhr call and the parsing from the view.js.
To do so I added :

In View.js

```
this._pagePromises.push(myapp.Services.Foo.getFoo()
.then(
    function success(results) {
      var x = results;
    },
    function error() {
      // TODO - handle the error.
    }
));
```

And in Services.js

```
Foo:
{   
    getFoo: function () {
        WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://sampleurl.com" }).done(
            function completed(request) {
                //parse request
                var obj = myapp.Parser.parse(request);
                return obj;
            },
            function error(request) {
                // handle error conditions.
            }
        );  
    }
}
```

But I have this exception :

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'then'
>   of undefined or null reference

What I want there is :
Start the promise in view.js do some stuff and update the view when getFoo() is completed. I'm not doing this the right way but as a C# developper I have some difficulties to understand this pattern.

Edit : 
There is my updated code:

```
getFoo: function () {
var promise = WinJS.xhr({ url: myapp.WebServices.getfooUrl() });
    promise.done(
        function completed(request) {
            var xmlElements = request.responseXML;
            var parser = new myapp.Parser.foo();
            var items = parser.parse(xmlElements);
            return items;
        },
        function error(request) {
            // handle error conditions.
        }
    );
    return promise;
}
```

It solved my issue about the 'then' but "return promise" is called before the "return items". So my "caller" does only get the promise and not his result.

What did I miss ?

Edit 2 : 
There is the correct way to do this :

```
Foo:
{
    getFooAsync: function () {
        return WinJS.Promise.wrap(this.getXmlFooAsync().then(
            function completed(request) {

                var xmlElements = request.responseXML;
                var parser = new myapp.Parser.Foo();
                var items = parser.parse(xmlElements);
                return items;
            }
        ));  
    },

    getXmlFooAsync: function () {
      return WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://sampleurl.com" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more compact way of doing this is to have your function return the return value from WinJS.xhr().then(). What this does is return a promise that will be fulfilled with the return value of your inner completed handler:

```
Foo:
{
    getFooAsync: function () {
        return WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://sampleurl.com" }).then(
            function completed(request) {
                var xmlElements = request.responseXML;
                var parser = new myapp.Parser.Foo();
                var items = parser.parse(xmlElements);
                return items;
            }
        ));  
    },
}
```

The caller can then use then/done on the promise it gets from getFooAsync, and the result in the completed handler will be *items* as returned by the completed handler. (You would not use .done inside this function because you're wanting to return a promise.)

This is the specified behavior of *then* in Promises-A, to allow for chaining. For more on this, see my post on the Windows 8 Developer Blog, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/06/11/all-about-promises-for-windows-store-apps-written-in-javascript.aspx.

Comment: True, it's better that way. Thank you.